# How to parse nested JSON objects starting with special characters in Unity?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get these information from MongoDB, and it is giving me this JSON to deal with:

```
{
    \"values\":
        [ 
            { \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"5ccf1bc55d0e652b8a6c9153\"} , \"Id\" : 5 ,\"Name\" : \" palups\"} , 
            { \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"5ccf24e91f6e4f29b5ede29b\"} , \"Id\" : 2 ,\"Name\" : \"Maria\"} , 
            { \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"5ccf25071f6e4f29b5ede2c5\"} , \"Id\" : 3 ,\"Name\" : \"marcela\"}
        ]
}
```

The problem is that nested object $oid. I managed to get the Id and the Name, but not the nested object.

Here's what I tried:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ScoreData {
    public List<Values> values = new List<Values>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Values
{
    public _id oid;
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class _id
{
    public string m_oid;
}
```

The part above are the classes that I created, and the code below is the function provided to me, with my additions to make it work the way I want:

```
IEnumerator getProductsInDB(){
    UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get (baseURL+databaseName+"/collections/"+collectionName+"?apiKey=" + apiKey);
    yield return unityWebRequest.Send();

    if(unityWebRequest.isNetworkError || unityWebRequest.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(unityWebRequest.error);
    }
    else {
        //Debug.Log (unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        jsonString = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text;

        string JSONToParse = "{\"values\":" + jsonString + "}"; //estava faltando no json ???

        ScoreData loadedScoreData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ScoreData>(JSONToParse);

        for (int i = 0; i <= loadedScoreData.values.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("score: " + loadedScoreData.values[i].oid.m_oid);
            Debug.Log("score: " + loadedScoreData.values[i].Id);
            Debug.Log("name: " + loadedScoreData.values[i].Name);
            Debug.Log("****************************************");
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I get on Unity's console:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/gQ2ZeZR]

(as you can see, the first line is empty).

> score:
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>
> score: 999
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>
> name:  Marcela
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

So, how to parse the nested value or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ViníciusPalu The posted "JSON" is not valid. The escape chars are in the wrong place for a valid JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `JsonUtility` the field names in your classes have to match with the ones in your JSON string. Otherwise the "missing" fields will simply have their default value (in your case `""`).

So from the naming in your JSON example

- in the class `Values` it should rather be

  ```
    public _id _id;
  ```
- in the class `_id` it **would** have to be

  ```
    public string $oid;
  ```

However the latter is not a valid [identifier name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#identifiers) in c#

> - **Identifiers must start with a letter, or `_`**.
> - Identifiers may contain Unicode letter characters, decimal digit characters, Unicode connecting characters, Unicode combining characters, or Unicode formatting characters. For more information on Unicode categories, see the Unicode Category Database. You can declare identifiers that match C# keywords by using the @ prefix on the identifier. The @ is not part of the identifier name. For example, @if declares an identifier named if. These verbatim identifiers are primarily for interoperability with identifiers declared in other languages.

The prefix `$` doesn't fit with those rules.

So if you can't change the JSON I fear that `JsonUtility` doesn't help you in this case and you should look for another Json parser.

---

You could e.g. use [`SimpleJson`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) in order to just retrieve this specific field for each `Values` instance afterwards and pass it in.

---

#### Anyway

The simplest solution would be to remove or replace that special character by something else before you parse it like e.g.

```
string JSONToParse = ("{\"values\":" + jsonString + "}").Replace('$', '_');
```

and rather change

```
[Serializeable]
public class _id
{
    public string _oid;
}
```

---

Also as Sir Rufo commented are you really sure you have to do that

```
string JSONToParse = ("{\"values\":" + jsonString + "}");
```

? In your question you are saying that you already receive the JSON including the `{ }` and the `values` field...

Comment: Is there any reason to concat the JsonToParse with the values part? To me this only adds noise

Comment: @SirRufo I don't know .. that what OP used as input so far and it seemed to me the rest of values basically is parsed correctly .. so I took it from OP's example.. but yes might be an additional error source

Comment: if I remove that line of code, Unity returns the following: ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.

Comment: @derHugo thank you very much for the help. I tried here and it worked just fine. I didn't know that for JsonUtility the field names in my classes had to match with the ones in myJSON string (althoug I was doing like that), so I dind't think about the replacing the $ or something like that. Again, thanks for saving my life haha